# Google Maps API - openInfoWindow is allways the same

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can set the makers (they appear on the map) but the infowindow is allways the same. I've tried with making an array for the infowindow content as well as for the makers but that also did not work.

```
  $(function() {
    map = $('#map_canvas');
    map.gmap().bind('init', function () {
      // Process the Microdata for each Event into an object.

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        url: "API",
        success: function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 301; i++) {

                  //details overlay
                   var eventDetails = '';
                    eventDetails += '<div class="iw">';
                    eventDetails += '<img src="'+ data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url+'"></img>';
                    eventDetails += '<h3>'+ data.data[i].tags + '</h3>';
                    eventDetails += '</div>';

                     //set location
                    var lat = data.data[i].location.latitude;
                    var lng = data.data[i].location.longitude;
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

                    //marker
                    var markerOptions = {
                      'bounds':true,
                      'position': latlng,
                      'icon': icon,
                    };

                    //add marker and set overlay
                    map.gmap('addMarker', markerOptions).click( function() {
                      map.gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': eventDetails }, this ); 
                    });
            }           
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about `gmap` but it looks like variable scoping problem to me and could be a solved as follows if everything else is alright

```
//add marker and set overlay
(function(mOpt, eDetails){
    map.gmap('addMarker', mOpt).click( function() {
        map.gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': eDetails }, this ); 
    });
})(markerOptions, eventDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience:

```
success: function(data) {

      $.each(data.data, function (i) {

        //details overlay
        var eventDetails = '';
        eventDetails += '<div class="iw">';
        eventDetails += '<img src="'+ data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url+'"></img>';
        eventDetails += '<h3>'+ data.data[i].tags + '</h3>';
        eventDetails += '</div>';

        //set location
        var lat = data.data[i].location.latitude;
        var lng = data.data[i].location.longitude;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        //marker
         var markerOptions = {
           'bounds':true,
           'position': latlng,
           'icon': icon,
         };

          //add marker and set overlay
          map.gmap('addMarker', markerOptions).click( function() {
              map.gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': eventDetails }, this ); 
          });
      });          
 }
```

This will work.